# "TemplateSyntaxError at / 'humanize' is not a registered tag library" in django

Tags: django, django-templates

when I tried to run the server I got this error.
I have added 'django.contrib.humanize' in my installed apps. and {% load humanize %} in my files.

**The error it shows :**

TemplateSyntaxError at /
'humanize' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_static
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
static
staticfiles
tz

Comment: if you are trying to see your application static humanize you just need {% load static %}

Comment: maybe you forgot add ```,``` in your installed apps

Comment: Please post your settings.py and a the template file you are using

Answer (score 0):

To activate these filters, add 'django.contrib.humanize' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting.py